# C array of pointers to strings, passing string from pointer

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of pointers to strings (char ** array), and I have a pointer, which points somewhere into this array (for example, third char of array[0]). I need use strncmp, where as second argument, I would pass string starting from where the pointer is.

i.e.:

```
char ** array = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*)*count);

array[0] = "Hello World";
char * p = array[0] + 3; /* just for example */
strncmp(query, ?, somemagicnumber);
```

what '?' should contain, in this case,  'lo World' (p points to second l in Hello);

How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try your code? What are the results?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question.  Do you want `strncmp(query, p, somemagicnumber);`?

Comment: Your `array[0] = "Hello World"` expression is wrong, to copy the string into `array[0]` use `strcpy(array[0], "Hello World")`. Since you are doing this `array[0] = malloc(n)`. And hence you are overwriting `array[0]` with another address.

Comment: @iharob The assignment is perfectly fine - he does not need to make a copy (although he certainly *can* make it if he wants to) Of course he's got a memory leak there.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Although the malloc above becomes completely useless and the memory is leaked, suggesting its not what the author intended. But sure per definition you're right, it's certainly valid, but stupid, to do so.

Comment: @Jite Yes - he needs to either remove the second `malloc`, or use `strcpy` like iharob suggests.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize, edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int strncmp(char *string1, char *string2, int n);
```

This is the prototype of `strncmp()`

In your case pass

```
strncmp("somestring",p,n); /* n = number of characters to be compared */
```